# Can a US permanent resident apply for a re-entry permit just because they want one?

Tags: greencard, usa

*Background:* A re-entry permit is a document that can be issued to a lawful permanent resident of the United States that is valid for up to 2 years and can be used in lieu of a green card when returning to the United States during its period of validity. The most common reason why LPRs apply for re-entry permits is that they want to travel outside the US for extended periods of time without being found to have abandoned their residence in the US.

Elsewhere (see [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/47922/can-lawful-permanent-residents-be-deported-from-the-us-for-arriving-at-a-port-of/47930#47930)) it is suggested that while an LPR who has lost their green card but manages to get to a port of entry can often manage to convince a CBP officer to admit them, this is not guaranteed. The LPR could be deported and banned from the US for 5 years. In the current political climate, some people might feel that they don't want to take such a risk.

It seems to me that it would be very convenient for an LPR to always possess a valid re-entry permit that is kept in a safe place. Therefore, if their green card should be lost or stolen during a trip outside the US, they could use the re-entry permit to ensure a smooth arrival back in the US while they wait for a replacement green card to be issued.

Now, the issuance of a re-entry permit is at the discretion of USCIS. On Form I-131, the applicant must state the intended dates and destinations of travel. Is there a strategy for the applicant, who wants a re-entry permit "just in case", to obtain an approval, notwithstanding the fact that they may not have any concrete travel plans, or may plan to only travel for very short durations?

Comment: Have you looked at the application fee for a reentry permit? It's $660 including the biometrics fee. Do you know what the legal basis for being refused entry or banned from the US might be?  Seeking entry without a green card is not a valid basis by itself.

Comment: @phoog Yes. That's why I want to know whether it's worthwhile to try to apply for one. If the application is denied, the fee is not refunded.

Comment: Why are you worried about being banned from the US?  If you do lose your green card and need to get a transportation letter from the consulate, that costs $575 too.  It seems to me that it's just better to safeguard the green card as something that costs several hundred dollars to replace.

Comment: @phoog See the linked question on Law Stack Exchange. INA 212(a)(7)(A)(i) is the legal basis for a finding of inadmissibility.

Comment: @phoog The Foreign Affairs Manual indicates that the purpose of a transportation letter is to permit a carrier to transport the alien to a port of entry. It does not entitle the alien to admission in the way that a green card would.

Comment: Obviously, green card holders should do their best to avoid losing their green card. However, accidents happen.

Comment: an LPR classifiable as a returning resident ([8 CFR 211.4)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/211.4) does not need a green card to be so classified.  A green card creates no entitlement to be admitted; that entitlement arises from having been previously admitted for permanent residence.

Comment: @phoog A returning resident *with* a valid unexpired green card is entitled to admission (unless some ground of inadmissibility applies). A returning resident *without* a green card or other specified document *may* be granted a waiver but is not entitled to one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102892/discussion-between-phoog-and-brian).

Comment: There's a difference between "just because they want one" and "in case they need to stay outside the US for more than 1 year". In my opinion, getting a re-entry permit to allow a potential stay outside for more than 1 year is a legitimate reason for getting a re-entry permit, even if you are not sure you are going to, or even if you don't plan to, stay outside that long, because plans can change and you are allowed to prepare for uncertainties. But if it's "just because they want one" to display on the wall or something, that would not be a legitimate reason to have it.

Comment: @user102008 It's not to display on the wall. It's for getting back to the US if the green card is lost or stolen while abroad. The alien in this situation may alternatively apply for a returning resident visa, but that seems like a lot of work.

Comment: Wouldn't taking photos of your green card go a long way in making a convincing argument at the border that you have a valid one (but it got stolen/lost)? And it's free.

Comment: @Aganju You are right, of course. But that doesn't protect you against an officer who just "doesn't like your face" and is determined to use their lawful discretion in order to deny you entry.

Comment: A _Re-entry Permit_ doesn't unconditionally allow you to entry either, so if he doesn't like your face, it is no good either.

Comment: @Aganju The difference is, if you show up and you have no green card and no reentry permit, there is a valid legal basis to have you deported, therefore the officer may invoke it just because they don't like your face. If you do have a reentry permit, there is not a valid legal basis to have you deported (unless there is some other requirement you failed to comply with).